# Bookmarking and page reloads with Backbone.js and pushState

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate

I've been trying to get various routes bookmarkable within my app, and this is possible if I don't have pushState enabled.  A user can enter mysite.com/#/view/30 and the proper view renders.

However, if I were to enable pushState and go to mysite.com/view/30 I receive a parse error (navigating there via the root page works fine).

I'm currently utilizing the Backbone.js Boilerplate using Require.js, and the parse error is appearing in my config.js file.  I'm fairly certain the issue isn't with Require but I'm not completely sure.  Frankly, I don't necessarily know what code to paste here either because I believe I'm more lacking a fundamental understanding a difference between hashbangs vs. pushState.

I've read up on the HTML5 feature, however the answer to my specific question still eludes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page with your Backbone router on does not exist at the path you are pointing to in your pushState. The pushState is purely to change the URL representation. You'd have to do some server config changes to route all of your requests back to a main index file.

Comment: Well, I use CodeIgniter as a framework and have setup routes that essentially duplicate the routes I have setup in my Backbone router.  However, they still don't behave as I expect them to unless I utilize the hashbang.